# Origin of the name "Slave I"

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, names, boba-fett

Are there any known in- or out-of-universe reasons for the name of Jango and Boba Fetts' ship, *Slave I*?

Answer (score 9):

In Legends continuity, it is because during the [Battle of Galidraan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Galidraan), the Mandalorians led by Jango Fett had been beaten and Jango, the only survivor, taken captive. He was taken into custody by the Governor of Galidraan and then sold into slavery. This takes place in [Jango Fett: Open Seasons 4](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jango_Fett:_Open_Seasons_4).

Comment: Could you provide a quote or a picture of the page?

Comment: I just read the Jango Fett series (thanks Marvel Unlimited!) and although Jango Fett was indeed a slave at one point, there isn't an explicit reference to him naming the ship for that reason.